# Link colors reversed?

Tags: discussion, css

On a Super User search page, link colors are set to this effect

```
.question-hyperlink {
  color: #1086a4;
}
.question-hyperlink:visited {
  color: #13b3bd;
}
```

Which equates out to a darker blue for links, and a lighter blue for visted links. Most sites I have come across over the years use the exact opposite convention; blue/lighter for links, purple/darker for visited links.

- [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com)
- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
- even [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

support this convention. What gives, Super User?

Comment: -1 I like it. Makes not yet visited pages stand out more.

Answer (score 1):

The W3C's [HTML 4 default stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) does not define colors and leading web usability consultant [Jakob Nielsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_Nielsen_%28usability_consultant%29) only argues that [unvisited and visited links should be different colors](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040503.html).

Since Super User does use different colors, one color not being darker or brighter than the other is trivial. If you must, you can use always a custom stylesheet in your web browser.